# Splitting a dataframe python

Tags: python

I have a data frame with a column titled 'Post Type'.

If the value in this column is 1, the post type is a question. If the value in this column is 2, the post type is an answer.

How can I return 2 new dataframes, one for questions and one for answers?

Answer (score 0):

```py
question_df = df[df["Post Type"] == 1]
answer_df = df[df["Post Type"] == 2]
```

Please refer [filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe)